# Redirect to the pentaho dashboard when user logging in

Tags: pentaho, pentaho-cde

First of all I have one dashboard. When pentaho user login, it show the dashboard (show full screen).

Meaning

After we start the tomcat server of pentaho i.e: http://localhost:8080/pentaho/. It display login screen after we type username and password.Immediately it will redirect to that dashoard.I want login screen of pentaho(I don't want popup of login screen)

Answer (score 0):

I assume the Pentaho user uses **Pentaho Login screen** (or Pentaho User Console screen) to log in to Pentaho Business Analytics server. So he accesses following URL:

`http://localhost:8080/pentaho/Home`

And he sees **Home** screen. Then he needs to navigate through **Browse Files** to choose particular dashboard and clicks **Open**. This opens the dashboard inside Pentaho.

My advise is: Use the **Open in a new window** to open the dashboard. This opens the dashboard in a new browser window. So you can **copy the URL** of your dashboard and provide to dashboard user. Dashboard URL is e.g.:

`http://localhost:8080/pentaho/api/repos/:home:MyDashboard.wcdf/generatedContent`

After Pentaho user accesses this URL he is prompt to log in. So he does not need to use the Pentaho Login screen and logs directly on your dashboard page.